# Text boxes overlap in windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, text, graphics, background

I have a problems with text boxes overlapping when I use an emulator with different screen size.  What is the best way to optimize my output so it is independent of phone screen size and resolution?

Here is an example of the issue I am running into

This is written in C# with XAML.

http://1drv.ms/1znAqJ9

thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they Overlap is because I believe you have explicitly defined the Margin Pixels in your Code which does not allow relative scaling on different sized phones.

As per your Images, I see you want text boxes in a Horizontal aligned Format.
So I suggest you Use a **Stack Panel** with the **Orientation Property set to Horizontal** and Add all your TextBoxes to the Stackpanel.

Then they will scale automatically in different Resolutions in Emulator.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I will give it a try and let you know.  Thanks